# Can mod_rewrite preserve a double slash?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Im just learning mod_rewrite and regex stuff, and what I'm trying to do is pass variables of any name, with any number of variables and values, into a script and have them forwarded to a different script.

here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^script\$(.*[\])? anotherscript?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&$1 [L]
```

That all seems to work except that one of the parameters I'm passing is a URL and the // after http:// always gets stripped down to one slash.

for example, I do

script$url=http://www.stackoverflow.com

then it redirects to:

anotherscript?ip=127.0.0.1&url=http:/www.stackoverflow.com

and the second script chokes on the single-slash.

I realize that preserving a double-slash is the exact opposite of what people usually do with mod_rewrite. Is there a way I can preserve the double-slash?

**EDIT**: Solution found with Gumbo's help.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)/script\$([^\s]+) 
RewriteRule ^script\$(.*) anotherscript?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&%2 [L]
```

I had to add that (.*) in front of /script on the RewriteCond, once I did that it got rid of the 404 errors and then it was just a matter of passing the matches through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /script\$([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^script\$.+ anotherscript?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&%1 [L]
```

See [Diggbar modrewrite- How do they pass URLs through modrewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831355/diggbar-modrewrite-how-do-they-pass-urls-through-modrewrite/869017#869017) for the explanation.

Comment: this is causing a 404 not found

Comment: Hope you didn’t forget the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Well it works for me. Have you already tried the internal logging feature for debugging? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Comment: I've enabled logging and all it says is "[Thu May 21 12:58:45 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/(path)" it looks like its trying to find a file called "script$id=123" instead of parsing that part out.

Comment: Try to disable MutliViews. That may cause Apache to look for alternatives before passing the request to mod_rewrite.

Comment: ok, im not sure that disabling Multiviews did anything but I did notice something: when there is a url in the request, the response is 403 with "(20024)The given path misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET " but when there is no URL its a 404 with the File does not exist error.

Comment: Have you thought about using another separator? And are there any other rules that could get in conflict with this rule?

Comment: I actually found a solution that was pretty close to your original suggestion. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I Think there may be something wrong with the first part of your RewriteRule regex

```
^script\$(.*[\])?
```

The backslash ( `\` ) is used to escape a special character into a litteral one, thus you are actually trying to match a closing bracket ( `]` ), is that intended ?

try this

```
RewriteRule ^script\$(.*)? anotherscript?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&$1 [L]
```

Comment: good catch, I removed that part and it still worked but the double-slash is still being converted to a single-slash.