# Issues when creating pretty URL that uses actual site urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to create functionality similar to the site downforeveryoneorjustme.com. They use a pretty URL to take in the URL of any given site. I sure they use htaccess to do this, however the method i'm using is encountering problems.

This is my .htaccess file that I'm using to send the site URL to a file.php:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /file.php?var=$1
```

However when I type in something like
`mysite.com/http://google.com` the variable it sends the file is `http:/google.com` (missing a slash). I can't figure out why this is occurring.

Also, when I type in something like `mysite.com/existingfolder`, where `existingfolder` is a folder on my site, it always works incorrectly. The variable it passes to the file is `missing.html` instead of `existingfolder`. In this case, the file doesn't display images. The image can't be found, and i'm assuming its because it's searching for the image in an incorrect folder on the site. That it might think it's in `existingfolder` and not in the normal folder it should be in.

Does anyone know why I'm getting these problems? I'm knew to htaccess, and I'm assuming it has something to do with that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889435/can-mod-rewrite-preserve-a-double-slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I sure they use htaccess to do this

I'm not. I'm not even sure they're using Apache.

mod_rewrite is not always the answer to all URL-processing problems. It's certainly prone to some of the quirks of path-based URL handling, including the removal of double-slashes.

I suggest reading the Apache-specific `REQUEST_URI` variable from your script, rather than relying on rewrites to get a parameter. This will give you the path requested by the browser without any processing.

Comment: How do I read the REQUEST_URI variable from my script?

Also, I've tried methods detailed in the linked questions, however none of those methods worked for me. 

                                            RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(https?://[^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^https?:/ file.php?var=%1 [L]
this is what was suggested on another page and it still didn't work for me