# Why django can not match double slashes correctly in URL?

Tags: django

I'm trying to use this URL pattern:

> (r'^welcome/(?P.+)/$', 'welcome'),

to match URL like this:

> http://localhost:9000/welcome/http://google.com/

but to my surprise, I found the value of next turned out to be:

> http:/google.com/

It seems that double slashes are somehow compressed into one slash.

Why django behave like this and is there workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Django ticket might get you going in the right direction: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14346

also: [Diggbar modrewrite- How do they pass URLs through modrewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831355/diggbar-modrewrite-how-do-they-pass-urls-through-modrewrite)