# url pattern working different behaviour between dev and prod - Django

Tags: regex, django, url-pattern

I'm having a problem with Django urlconf.

Basically I've this pattern:

`^publication/(?P<pub_search>[\w\.=&]+)?(/keyword/(?P<key_search>[\w=&]+))?(/author/(?P<auth_search>[\w=&]+))?(/tag/(?P<tag_search>[\w=&]+))?(/from/(?P<from_date>[\w\d=&]+))?(/until/(?P<until_date>[\w\d=&]+))?$`

According this pattern, I should be able to have an URL of this form:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/publication//author/name=crock`

Indeed this url form is recognized in my django dev server. But on the production server (Apache + mod_wsgi) it doesn't match the url.

I've no idea of the reason why it acts this way on prod server.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache removes multiple slashes inside the path. You can fix this with some mod_rewrite magic.

Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831355/diggbar-modrewrite-how-do-they-pass-urls-through-modrewrite/869017#869017):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(https?://[^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^https?:/ index.php?url=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm quite noob with mod_rewrite... How should I write the rule to allow doubleslashes for all urls under http://www.example.com/ckp/ for instance ?

Comment: I'm no expert on mod_rewrite either. I added an example but googling around should help you. Either way, I would see if you can get rid of the double slash in the url pattern..